# Site Logo Missing under SSL

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

Under System > Configuration > General > Design > Header > Logo Image Src with http the following worked perfectly:
images/media/my_shiny_logo.png

However, after successfully activating SSL (setting secure Base URL to `https://www.example.com/`) everything ***except the site logo*** works as expected.

The source code of `https://www.example.com/store1/index.php/checkout/onepage/` reveals:

```
<img class="large" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/skin/frontend/store1/default/images/media/my_shiny_logo.png">
```

Should Magento not automagically redirect the https request? It's another Magento Mystery...

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The problem was not with Magento but with Hotlink protection on the host server which needed to be configured to permit access from `https://www.example.com` as well as the existing access from `http://www.example.com`. Mystery solved :)

Answer (score 0):

is this the actual url of your logo? (Except fo the dummies of course ;))

Do you use a self-made ssl cert or maybe a cdn?

Also outdated packages on your (I'm really not sure if those affect you if you have them on your client or server) could cause a problem.

or maybe(nothing related to ssl actually) did you install the latest security patch lately

Comment: URL is accurate (except 'example.com' obviously). Geotrust SSL, no CDN and clean 1.9.2.2 install though latest patch not yet applied.

Comment: (overran the 5 minutes edit time!).... URL is accurate (except 'example.com' obviously). Geotrust issued SSL, no CDN and clean 1.9.2.2 install though very latest patch not yet applied. As stated, under http logo appears on all non-secure pages; but only alt text showing on secure checkout page under https. Thanks David.